# Expo push-notification not working in production

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo, foreground-service

SDK Version: 40
Platform: Android

The push notification is only working in development mode in development device it’s not working in development mode (usb yarn react-n run-android) in other device… (fcm setted) after I build using bundleRelease (eject) and published to playstore. it’s not working could I set as production in google console or expo console ? where ? I’m testing with insomnia (exp.host/–/api/v2/push/send) and it’s ok in development, but not in other devices and production , why working in one device and not in others device in test ? I see the exponent push generated after install as well.

OBS: I’m refreshing the new tokens after install the app again…

I recently tried:

I generated the .apk and try in another device but not worked just in my development device

```
// Notifications.setNotificationHandler(null); //tried as well

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
handleNotification: async () => {
return {
shouldShowAlert: true,
shouldPlaySound: true,
shouldSetBadge: false,
};
},
});
```

the problem is caused because I’m using gradlew assembleRelease to build ? Need I build with eas build platform android ???

I'm currently using exeperienceId: @username/slug and not ApplicationId to register the push tokens

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 reasons your notifications are not working in production.

1. I think you are creating a notification token using `Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()` which will create a notification token that can only be used in the Expo environment. I suggest you make the notification token using `Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync()` which will create a notification token that can be used with FCM.
2. You are calling the Expo API `exp.host/–/api/v2/push/send` which is not correct. If you want to get your notification working on a physical device, you need to first create a Device token that you can generate as mentioned in point 1 and then you are supposed to call FCM API `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Someone said u today that u're beautiful ? It works , the body to request below: {   "to": "token", "notification": {  "title": "title",  "body": "body",  "icon": "icone_da_notificacao" },   "data": {} } , Header -> Authorization: key=fcm_cloud_msg_TOOOOOOKKKEEEEEEEEENNNNNNN

Comment: But what u think is happening that my background task is not showing my notification ? just on development mode... push is solved as u mentioned but my background notification not showing yet =/

Comment: What do you mean by background notification? Is it when the app is running in the background and you're not getting the notifications ?

Comment: URL "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" didn't work for me. Only "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send" worked.